# How to derive the expression for the effective potential in Kohn-Sham operator in Kohn-Sham density functional theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body, density-functional-theory

In density functional theory the Kohn-Sham method provides a systematic way to approaching the correct electron density of a given system. Kohn-Sham method uses a non-interacting reference system built from a set of one-electron orbitals $\phi_i$. The local, effective potential $V_S(r)$ has to be chosen such that the electron density $\rho_S(r)$ obtained from the summation of the moduli of the squared spin orbitals exactly equals the ground-state density of the real system of interacting electrons
\begin{equation}
\rho_S(r) = \sum_{i}^{N}\sum_s|\phi_i(r, s)|^2 = \rho_0(r)
\end{equation}
Here $N$ is the number of particels in the non-interacting system. The spin orbitals $\phi_i$ denote the probability of finding an electron with certain spin from certain volume element. These spin orbitals are called the Kohn-Sham orbitals and they define the ground-state wave function of the non-interacting system. The Kohn-Sham orbitals are determined by
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}^{KS}\phi_i = \varepsilon_i\phi_i
\end{equation}
Operator $\hat{f}^{KS}$ is called the one-electron Kohn-Sham operator and it is defined as
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}^{KS} = -\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 + V_S(r)
\end{equation}
Here $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian. As mentioned before, $V_S(r)$ has to be chosen so that the first equation holds ($\rho_S(r) = \rho_0(r)$). The expression for $V_S$ is as follows
\begin{equation}\
V_S(r) = \int\frac{\rho(r_2)}{r_{12}}\,dr_2 - \sum_A^M\frac{Z_A}{R_{1A}} + V_{XC}(r_1)
\end{equation}
The first term is classical Coulomb potential and the second term is potential due to the atomic nuclei. The last term is a functional derivative of the exchange-correlation energy $E_{XC}[\rho(r)]$ with respect to electron density. Variable $r_{12}$ is the distance between particles 1 and 2. $M$ is the number of nuclei and $Z_A$ is the atomic number of nucleus $A$.

What I don't understand is how this expression for $V_S(r)$ is derived. I have read so many books, articles and watched multiple videos but I cannot find an accurate derivation anywhere. I just don't understand where this comes from. The fact that all books use slightly different notations makes this even harder to understand. I have read, for example "A Chemist’s Guide to Density Functional Theory" by Koch and Holthausen. There they said that the detailed derivation for this is given in "Density-Functional Theory of Atoms and Molecules" by Parr and Yang. I also checked that but still don't understand.

Can anyone make a detailed but clear derivation where the equation for $V_S$ comes from?

Comment: See for example: Section 3.1. of *Density Functional Theory. An Advanced Course. E. Engel and R. Dreizler. Springer Theoretical and Mathematical Physics.* Also, what's wrong with the derivation in Parr and Yang?

Comment: Additionally, it might be worth to ask this question on [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/). But please make sure to indicate it as a [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).